# Buttons in message box in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a tic tac toe program and i have the board set up, and the game works for the majority. determining who wins. what i am trying to do right now is after a winner is determined, a message box pops up and says who ever wins. I would like the message box to contain two buttons. One button with the text, "Ok for new game" and the second button with the text, "Cancel to exit". I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Here is the code I have:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private turn As Integer = 1
    Private play() As String = {"O", "X"}
    Private board(2, 2) As String

    Private Structure arrayIndex
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
    End Structure

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For x As Integer = 1 To 9
            Dim b As New Button With { _
                .Width = 80, _
                .Height = 80, _
                .Text = "", _
                .Location = New Point(60 + (((x - 1) Mod 3) * 80), 60 + (((x - 1) \ 3) * 80)), _
                .Tag = New arrayIndex With {.x = (x - 1) Mod 3, .y = (x - 1) \ 3}}
            Me.Controls.Add(b)
            AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf buttons_click

        Next
        Me.SetClientSizeCore(360, 360)


    End Sub

    Private Sub buttons_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If DirectCast(sender, Button).Text <> "" Then Return
        DirectCast(sender, Button).Text = play(turn Mod 2)
        Dim index As arrayIndex = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag, arrayIndex)
        board(index.x, index.y) = play(turn Mod 2)
        turn += 1
        winner()
    End Sub

    Private Sub winner()
        Dim rows(7) As String

        rows(0) = board(0, 0) & board(1, 0) & board(2, 0)
        rows(1) = board(0, 1) & board(1, 1) & board(2, 1)
        rows(2) = board(0, 2) & board(1, 2) & board(2, 2)
        rows(3) = board(0, 0) & board(0, 1) & board(0, 2)
        rows(4) = board(1, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(1, 2)
        rows(5) = board(2, 0) & board(2, 1) & board(2, 2)
        rows(6) = board(0, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(2, 2)
        rows(7) = board(2, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(0, 2)

        For x As Integer = 0 To 7
            If rows(x).Length = 3 AndAlso (rows(x)(0) = rows(x)(1) AndAlso rows(x)(0) = rows(x)(2)) Then
                MessageBox.Show(rows(x)(0) & "'s winsssss!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            If DialogResult.OK Then
            turn = 1
            ReDim board(2, 2)
            For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
            ctrl.Text = ""
            Next
            Return
            Else
               Me.Close()


            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Code tip: You don't need the `_` line continuation most of the time in VB 2010.

Comment: ok, i just decided to include them in, just in case. thanks for the tip. do you have any ideas on how to help with my problem?

Comment: Sure - it's not possible with `MsgBox`. You'll need to make another `Form` - but that's not too time-consuming.

Comment: could i use MsgBoxStyle? and when Ok is clicked, could i have it so that way the board is created and when cancel is clicked, to close the program?

Comment: Sure you can use `MsgBoxStyle` (though I would recommend actually using the native .NET `MessageBox.Show`) but you won't get your custom button text.

Comment: ok. i can't remember exactly how to have it so ok and cancel are the two buttons. i can only see the ok button with what i have so far. here is what i have.     MessageBox.Show(rows(x)(0) & "'s winsssss!")

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(rows(x)(0) & "'s winsssss!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)`

Comment: ok, thank you. how do i do an onclick for the buttons? i can't seem to remember. a lot of coding going through my head right now. lol

Comment: If the return value is `DialogResult.OK`, the user pressed OK. Otherwise, it was Cancel.

Comment: ok. thank you. i got it to work, but when i click cancel, it clears the board as well. what i have commented out in my winner function i used if OK was clicked, and i used Me.Close() when cancel was clicked. but it doesn't work out. am i doing something wrong there?

Comment: Can you post your updated code, please?

Comment: ok, i just edited the code and updated it

Comment: or, i just thought of this, since the board is being created when the form is loaded, could i add two buttons on my form design, but with the code i have now, how would i keep the text on the two buttons? since i am clearing all the contents in each of the buttons

Comment: You wrote `If DialogResult.OK`. That will always execute. The function *returns* the value. `If MessageBox.Show(rows(x)(0) & "'s winsssss!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.OK Then '...`

Comment: ok cool. thats works perfectly! thank you very much. one last final problem with this code. For some reason, i just can't seem to figure out how to code if there is a tie. I'm not sure why. Could you help with that?

Comment: That's a different question altogether :) You should ask that in another question.

Comment: yea, i understand. i'll put that in a different question. make things easier

Comment: moved the new question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123342/tic-tac-toe-coding-for-tie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is by creating a new `Form` that functions as a `MessageBox`. There are many `API` to customized the `MessageBox` but gives you extra time. So this is what you are going to do.

- Create a new Form
- Set MaximizeButton, MinimizeButton and ShowOnTitleBar to `False`
- Set `FormBorderStyle` to FixedDialog so it will not be sizeable
- Add two buttons on it (`Ok for new game` and `Cancel to exit`)
- Set `StartUpPosition` to `CenterForm`

Add this code to `On for New Game Button` (**Click event**)

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes
```

Add this code to `Cancel to exit` (**Click event**)

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.No
```

When the game is finished, try to call the new form you have created.

```
Dim xForm as new frmAsk ' Assuming that frmAsk is the name of your new form
If xForm.showDialog = DialogResult.Yes Then
    ' New game here
Else
    ' exit game
End If
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: would i add the last piece of code in the first form that i created? or does that go into the new form?

Comment: only the `dialogresult` will be added on the new form. `Dim xForm...` will be added on the first form.

Comment: for your example, the new form name, frmAsk, it was saying that frmAsk is not declared

Comment: actually, nevermind, that does work. i did not add the new form in my project.

Comment: would you also be able to help me out when there is a tie?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this :

```
If Msgbox("Your text here") <> MsgboxResult.Yes then
    Exit
Else
    Your code there to continue the game.
End if
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your input and help. but do you think you could help me out with coding if there is a tie? i know i would have to create a boolean variable to see if the space is filled. but not sure how to actually code it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Case msgbox("You Win! Do you want to play another game?",vbYesNo)
    case vbYes
        'add code to start a new game
    case vbNo
        'add code to exit your app
        Unload Me
End Select
```

Comment: I've got this working, now. but i'm trying to write the code for when there is a tie. I can't seem to really figure that part out. and i'm not sure why.