# coding a tie in tic tac toe

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tic tac toe coding for tie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123342/tic-tac-toe-coding-for-tie)

I have a tic tac toe program and I've got everything working that way it should be. But, the one final problem I am having with this coding is that I can't seem to figure out when there is a tie how to code it. here is what i have so far.

```
Public Class Form1

Private turn As Integer = 1
Private play() As String = {"O", "X"}
Private board(2, 2) As String

Private Structure arrayIndex
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For x As Integer = 1 To 9
        Dim b As New Button With { _
            .Width = 80, _
            .Height = 80, _
            .Text = "", _
            .Location = New Point(60 + (((x - 1) Mod 3) * 80), 60 + (((x - 1) \ 3) * 80)), _
            .Tag = New arrayIndex With {.x = (x - 1) Mod 3, .y = (x - 1) \ 3}}
        Me.Controls.Add(b)
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf buttons_click

    Next
    Me.SetClientSizeCore(360, 360)

End Sub

Private Sub buttons_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If DirectCast(sender, Button).Text <> "" Then Return
    DirectCast(sender, Button).Text = play(turn Mod 2)
    Dim index As arrayIndex = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag, arrayIndex)
    board(index.x, index.y) = play(turn Mod 2)
    turn += 1
    winner()
End Sub

Private Sub winner()
    Dim rows(7) As String
    rows(0) = board(0, 0) & board(1, 0) & board(2, 0)
    rows(1) = board(0, 1) & board(1, 1) & board(2, 1)
    rows(2) = board(0, 2) & board(1, 2) & board(2, 2)
    rows(3) = board(0, 0) & board(0, 1) & board(0, 2)
    rows(4) = board(1, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(1, 2)
    rows(5) = board(2, 0) & board(2, 1) & board(2, 2)
    rows(6) = board(0, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(2, 2)
    rows(7) = board(2, 0) & board(1, 1) & board(0, 2)

    For x As Integer = 0 To 7
        If rows(x).Length = 3 AndAlso (rows(x)(0) = rows(x)(1) AndAlso rows(x)(0) = rows(x)(2)) Then
            If MessageBox.Show(rows(x)(0) & "'s winsssss!", "We have a winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.OK Then
                turn = 1
                ReDim board(2, 2)
                For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
                    ctrl.Text = ""
                Next
                Return
            Else
                Me.Close()


            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: i know. thinking that reposting would put the question on top of the list. but i've been trying to work on this, but just can't seem to figure it out

Comment: -1, reposting a question you've already asked is unacceptable. See [this entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions) in the FAQ for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `Me.close()`, that's where it would say that you had a tie. Basically the logic you put into this is simple, if a side (either x's or o's) wins, then there will be a message box that shows it. Then you reset the game and return. After that there's the `else` statement that has `Me.close()` the `else` means that no one has won the game, so it is assumed that there is a tie. (if all of the spaces are filled)

Comment: the Me.close() is for when cancel is clicked. but i'm trying to figure out, when all of the spaces are filled, there's a tie, but also have a message box to show up saying that there is a tie. but i can't figure out the coding for it

Comment: and also, if i code that there was a tie in the else part, how would i know that all of the spaces are filled?

Comment: It's the same thing as the win message box. Just use this code logic under the `else` statement that you had `Me.close()` in. Else if all the spaces are filled, then it is a tie. Else, then the user must have canceled, we should close the program.

Comment: i'm trying to see what you mean, but i'm having trouble seeing it. would i have to create a variable that says that the spaces are filled?

Comment: And to find out if all the spaces are filled, just loop through every space, if it's not filled, then make it exit the program, since it would be expected that the user pressed cancel then. Right outside of that loop, make a messagebox that says there was a tie. Basically, if all the spaces are filled, it will pass the loop without any problem, and move on to the code right after the loop, which would be the 'we have a tie' message.

Comment: if there is a tie, i don't want the program to be exited. I would still like to have a message box come up saying that there was a tie, but also have the ok and cancel buttons.

Comment: would you be able to give me an example using code? because i'm not really seeing how to implement everything that you are talking about